# Exponential Test

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, density-function, exponential-distribution

Given a collection of data points, without any other information I want to test for an exponential distribution. In a different case, I tested for normality using an Accord implementation of the Shapiro-Wilk Test, is there something similar for exponential?

Comment: Just in case this question gets no response, one might try the [statistics site](https://stats.stackexchange.com).